# Read one record/item and write multiple records/items using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I did some searching but couldn't find any sample/example.

I've a requirement where geo coordinates from one table (input) are read, processed to generate POI's associated to coordinate. So one geo coordinate will result in one or more POI's that needs to be inserted into another table (output).

I'm currently using a JdbcCursorItemReader and JdbcBatchItemWriter to read one item/record and write one item/record. There is also an ItemProcessor that generates the POI's for a give geo coordinate.

Does a custom JdbcBatchItemWriter help me achieve this?

Any ideas? TIA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you just want to spread the items to different writers (read duplicate output) you can use the existing [CompositeItemWriter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html)

but i'm not sure if your processor will produce different item types or if you want to spread the content of one complex item type to multiple writers, for those cases you can use a slightly changed version for a [multiline-record-writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836689/spring-batch-multi-line-record-item-writer-with-variable-number-of-lines-per-rec/7841510#comment9568144_7841510) question

```
public class MultiOutputItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object> {

private JdbcBatchItemWriter<ClassFoo> delegateFoo;
private JdbcBatchItemWriter<ClassBar> delegateBar;

public void write(List<? extends Object> items) throws Exception {
       // if you have different types of items
       // check Object Class
       // add to new List<Classfoo>
       // call delegate e.g. delegateFoo.write(List with ClassFoo);
       //
       // or if you have complex objects
       // same procedure as above, but with
       // add to new List<Classfoo> with item.getClassFoo
 }
}
```

if you use FlatFileItemWriter, do not forget to [register the delegates as ItemStreams](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#registeringItemStreams) (so spring batch will open/close them for you)

Comment: thanks michael. i continued to look for answers and have arrived at more or less the same solution. my item processor is currently generating single item but i could modify it to return a list of items. i plan to use single writer and write multiple items of same type into a table. i'll give it a shot and see if works for me.

Comment: this worked for me. i used a processor that was returning a List of items and a writer as suggested above. however i used a plain jdbc template w/ batch update to insert the items into db. the critical part was 'List<? extends Object> items'. i wasn't familiar w/ this notation and was trying to read items from the list. thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 12):

What you are really looking for is called a [Splitter](http://eaipatterns.com/Sequencer.html) pattern:

[image]

Here is how it is defined in [Spring Integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#overview-endpoints-splitter):

*A Splitter is a type of Message Endpoint whose responsibility is to accept a Message from its input channel, split that Message into multiple Messages, and then send each of those to its output channel. This is typically used for dividing a "composite" payload object into a group of Messages containing the sub-divided payloads.*

Configuration is extremely simple:

```xml
<channel id="inputChannel"/>

<splitter id="splitter" 
  ref="splitterBean" 
  method="split" 
  input-channel="inputChannel" 
  output-channel="outputChannel" />

<channel id="outputChannel"/>

<beans:bean id="splitterBean" class="sample.PojoSplitter"/>
```

Or you can use annotations:

```java
@Splitter
List<LineItem> extractItems(Order order) {
    return order.getItems()
}
```

You can of course write your own `JdbcBatchItemWriter` if it feels simpler. However Spring Integration already does it for you.

You can use [Spring Integration JDBC Support](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc) => `jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter` / `jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter` and the above splitter to achieve what you want and.. simplicity.

Comment: just curious, does restart work with spring integration too? or in other words, is spring integration just a thin pluggable module ?

Comment: you can definitely do rerun vs restart ( it is a philosophical discussion, since rerun is cleaner :). But in case you'd like to use it from within Spring Batch ( thin pluggable module ), you can. Although for @user977505 situation, Spring Integration alone with possibly some SB components ( or not ) will do just fine.

Comment: thanks for responding. i'll give it a shot and update the thread.

Comment: has anyone done this? or have links to code that does? I looked through some spring integration documentation but couldn't find much besides a mention that it was possible

Comment: Where does the `@Splitter` annotation go?

Answer (score 1):

I did this by extending the Writer class (in my case HibernateItemWriter). I see one answer describes how to use a 'splitter'. If anyone has a working example of how that might work in an environment using the spring-boot-starter-parent, I would love to see it. For what I am doing (creating a List from a single record) it would be so much easier if Spring provided a write method that handled a List of Lists.

Here is how I extended the Writer to handle multiple writes for every line read/processed: [Spring-Batch Multi-line record Item Writer with variable number of lines per record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836689/spring-batch-multi-line-record-item-writer-with-variable-number-of-lines-per-rec/27789307#27789307)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case and i could solve it with the following reusable code:

```
@Slf4j
public class ListItemWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<List<T>> {

  private ItemWriter<T> delegate;

  @Setter private int chunkSize = 0;

  public ListItemWriter(ItemWriter<T> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends List<T>> items) throws Exception {
    if (chunkSize == 0) {
      chunkSize = items.size();
    }
    List<T> allItems = items.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    log.info("writing {} items", allItems.size());
    List<List<T>> partitions = ListUtils.partition(allItems, chunkSize);
    for (List<T> partition : partitions) {
      delegate.write(partition);
    }
  }
}
```

Reader: A 
Processor: A -> List<B> 
Writer: new ListItemWriter(ItemWriterForB)