# Spring batch item splitter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, jobs, spring-integration

I have the following issue:  I have a file where each line results in 1 or more items being written to a database.  I need to do a lookup from another system to find out how many items need to be written.  Each of the items resulting from a single line must be transformed using a chain of item processors and finally written to multiple tables in a DB.

Because each item needs to write to multiple tables, they must each be in their own transaction.  Because of this, I can't just have an `ItemProcessor<Foo, List<Bar>>` which handles it.  In that case -- even with a `commit-interval` of 1 -- I would end up with multiple items in the same transaction.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894445/read-one-record-item-and-write-multiple-records-items-using-spring-batch) stack overflow question already.  The accepted answer doesn't help me because of the transaction issue.  The other answer about using a Spring Integration splitter sounds intriguing.  However, it doesn't give a ton of details.  How do I define the reader's output as the channel input?  How would I define an output channel which goes to my item writer?  How could I still run an item processor chain on each newly divided item?

I haven't been able to find any examples using the splitter within a spring batch job.  Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use a ClassifierCompositeItemWriter http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html

Comment: @SerkanArıkuşu There is nothing here that needs classified.  Everything is going to the same writer.  I believe a composite item writer is used for having certain items go to certain item writers based on a classifier.  If I'm missing something, please let me know.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution in this? I do have the exact same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problematic with FlatFileItemReader, minus the transaction issue though.
Dealt with it that way :

```
public class FlatFileItemListWriter<T> extends FlatFileItemWriter<T> {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * 
     * @see org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter#write(java.util.List)
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void write(List<? extends T> itemsLists) throws Exception {
        List<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (Object item : itemsLists) {
            items.addAll((List<T>) item);
        }
        super.write(items);
    }

}
```

That way, the FlatFileItemWriter deals with the list the way it would have if my processor didn't produce lists.