# Read one line write multiple row

Tags: spring-batch

I read a csv file with spring batch. I use FlatFileItemReader.

```
id number | score 1 | score 2 |  score 3
```

I need to take this line and create multiple record because the database is in this format

```
id number 
score
```

So in this example I would need to create 3 record

```
id number | score 1
id number | score 2
id number | score 3
```

Is there a way to take this line and convert it to write multiple row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read one record/item and write multiple records/items using spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894445/read-one-record-item-and-write-multiple-records-items-using-spring-batch)

Comment: not realy, accepted answer talk about having different writer with different object.

Comment: In this case, you can use an item processor that transforms an input item into 3 output items.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine that mean, item processor will return a list of item? Anything special for the writer? do you have any example?

Comment: yes `ItemProcessor<Item, List<Item>>` and `ItemWriter<List<List<Item>>`. That's what your requirement is right? I don't have an example right now, but give it a try and if you need support, you can share what you tried I will try help.