# Spring Batch: How to Insert multiple key-value pairs into Database table for each item

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, spring-batch, key-value

After processing some XML files with Spring Batch ItemProcessor.
The ItemProcessor returns items like this:

```
MetsModsDef
{
   int id;
   String title;
   String path;
   Properties identifers;
   ....
}
```

now  i need to save  this items into a database, so that the
   (id, title, path) will go into the "Work" table

and all the Properties stored in the  "identifiers" field go into a "Key/Value"-Table called "Identifier" (work, identitytype, identityValue)

how can i acheive this?

currently i am using a CompositeItemWriter  to split the object and write it into two tables like this:

```
   public ItemWriter<MetsModsDef> MultiTableJdbcWriter(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

    CompositeItemWriter<MetsModsDef> cWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<MetsModsDef>();

    JdbcBatchItemWriter hsqlWorkWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder()
        .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
        .sql("INSERT INTO work (id, title, path,enabled) VALUES (:id, :title,:path,1)" )
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .build();

    JdbcBatchItemWriter hsqlIdentifierWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder()
        .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
        .sql("INSERT INTO identity (work, identitytype, identityValue) VALUES (:work, :identitytype, :identityValue)" )
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .build();

    List<ItemWriter<? super MetsModsDef>> mWriter = new ArrayList<ItemWriter<? super MetsModsDef>>();
    mWriter.add(hsqlWorkWriter);
    mWriter.add(hsqlIdentifierWriter);
    cWriter.setDelegates(mWriter);
```

but this will not work  for a propertylist since (work, identitytype, identityValue)  are not part of my domain object MetModsDef which only contains one map of properties which are supposed to go into the Identifier table.

i have found advice on how to do it when writing to a file, 
and even on using a splitter pattern from Spring-Integration [Read one record/item and write multiple records/items using spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894445/read-one-record-item-and-write-multiple-records-items-using-spring-batch)
but i am still not sure how to actually do it, when writing out via jdbc or hibernate (which i assume would be similarish )
thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 1):

in case somebody is interested: after a while i have come up with own solution:
I have found one  extending HibernateItemWriter (for hibernate writes) on the internet:

[Spring-Batch Multi-line record Item Writer with variable number of lines per record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836689/spring-batch-multi-line-record-item-writer-with-variable-number-of-lines-per-rec/27789307#27789307)
but i did not want to extend classes, so i had to come up with my own (based on what i could research on the internet).

I am not sure how good is, and how it will handle transactions or rollback (probably bad). but for now it is the only one i have. So if you need one too, or have comments on how to improve it. or even have a better one. You are very welcome.
i have created my own IdentifierListWriter which creates the Key/value-pairs-like-objects (here each pair is called "identitifier") for each MetsModsDef Item and writes out them all using JdbcBatchItemWriter identifierWriter wich is passed to it from the configuration

```
    public class IdentifierListWriter implements ItemWriter<MetsModsDef>
{
    private ItemWriter<Identifier>      _identifierWriter;

    public IdentifierListWriter ( JdbcBatchItemWriter<Identifier> identifierWriter )
    {
        _identifierWriter= identifierWriter;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void write(List<? extends MetsModsDef> items) throws Exception
    {
        // Main Table WRITER
        for ( MetsModsDef item : items )
        {
            ArrayList<Identifier> ids = new ArrayList<Identifier>();
            for(String key : item.getAllIds().stringPropertyNames())
            {
             ids.add(new Identifier(item.getAllIds().getProperty(key),
                     key, item.getId()));
            }
            _identifierWriter.write(ids);
      }
    }
}
```

In the java configuration i create two jdbcBatchItemWriter Beans. One for the "Work" table and one for the "identifier" table. IdentifierListWriter bean and a CompositeItemWriter MultiTableJdbcWriter Bean which uses them all to write out the object

```
 @Bean
@Primary
public ItemWriter<MetsModsDef> MultiTableJdbcWriter(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

    IdentifierListWriter identifierListWriter = new IdentifierListWriter(identifierWriter(dataSource) );

    CompositeItemWriter cWriter = new CompositeItemWriter();
    cWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(hsqlWorkWriter(dataSource),identifierListWriter));
    return cWriter;
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<MetsModsDef> hsqlWorkWriter(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<MetsModsDef>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql("INSERT INTO work (id, title, path,enabled) VALUES (:id, :title,:path,1)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();

}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Identifier> identifierWriter(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql("INSERT INTO identifier (identifier, type, work_id) VALUES ( :identifier, :type, :work)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            //.afterPropertiesSet()
            .build();
}
```

then the multiTableJdbcWriter is called from a Step:

```
   @Bean
public Step step1(ItemWriter<MetsModsDef> multiTableJdbcWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<StreamSource, MetsModsDef>chunk(1)
            .reader(new MetsModsReader())
            .processor(metsModsFileProcessor())
            .writer(multiTableJdbcWriter)
```